# Is there a better way to write this code, should I have the global variables before the function prototype instead?

Tags: python-3.x

This code is supposed to take two inputs from the user and then sum them. If the result is between 15 and 20, it should print '20' and if it is any other, it should print the exact summed answer.

```
def mysum (x,y):

total = x+y

if total in range (15,20):

    print ('20')

else:

    print (total)

x = int(input("Input the number:  "))
y = int(input("Input the number:  "))
mysum(x,y)
```

Comment: Instead of `range(15, 20)` you should use `15 <= total <= 20` - which will be more efficient. Otherwise, it's fine. No need to change anything.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It's hard to tell where the function is supposed to end. It's best to paste the code in and apply the formatting to the whole block, rather than trying to fix it manually.

Comment: (I've reverted someone else's attempt at fixing the indentation, as I'm fairly sure it wasn't correct. Please be very cautious what assumptions you're making when changing the indentation of someone else's python post.)

Comment: @rdas In Python3 (which this question is tagged) the contains-check of a `range` is `O(1)`, so no asymptotic complexity difference. Otherwise, your suggestion is, of course, better and more universal, e.g. accepts floats.

Comment: @schwobaseggl it also avoids creating the `range` object in each invocation

Comment: @rdas No objections :) just meant to point out that the range does not get iterated.  Nitpicking: the second `<=` should be a `<` if it were to be equivalent to the range code, which may or may not be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can say this is *better*, but here are 2 ways to do it differently:

Here, I do the exactly the same as you did but a bit shorter: (maybe less clear too?)

```
def mysum(x, y):
  print("20" if 15 <= x+y < 20 else str(x + y))

x = int(input("Input the number:  "))
y = int(input("Input the number:  "))
mysum(x,y)
```

There, I put everything inside the `mysum` function (and used the shorther syntax of the first way):

```
def mysum(): # No arguments
  x = int(input("Input the number:  "))
  y = int(input("Input the number:  "))
  print("20" if 15 <= x+y < 20 else str(x + y))

mysum()
```

Note that the `mysum` function no longer requires arguments this way. Maybe you'd prefer it that way, maybe you don't (because you want to re-use `x` and `y` later in the code, for instance).